# How to implement 'user can only edit his own post/model' in Laravel

Tags: laravel, permissions, roles

Some models can only be edited/deleted by its owner:

```
$model->user_id
```

Is this how I should check whether the user owns a model (in every controller action that needs it?):

```
if ($model->user_id == Auth::user()->id)
```

Seems redundant to add this in every Controller Action that needs this check? I am looking for an elegant and DRY solution (filters? role based permissions?)

Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an possible thing that makes sense to do if you want users to edit ongly their own posts.

In your **Post model**, create this function:

```
  public function isTheOwner($user)
  {
    return $this->user_id === $user->id;
  }
```

Next, in your **PostController**

```
  public function getEdit($id)
  {
    // 1st # Fetch the post with something like this:
    $post      = $this->post->findOrFail($id); // maybe this will not work for you, try to implement your own method here

    // 2nd # Here is how you do the trick
    // validate that the user updating the post is the post author:
    if ( ! $post->isTheOwner(Auth::user())) return \Redirect::to('/');

    // 3rd # Return the view with the post array

  }
```

Answer (score 1):

**Updated answer**

Use the form request class authorize method.

```
public function authorize()
{
    $commentId = $this->route('comment');

    return Comment::where('id', $commentId)
                  ->where('user_id', Auth::id())->exists();
}
```

Docs: https://laravel.com/docs/5.0/validation#form-request-validation

Tutorial: https://laracasts.com/series/laravel-from-scratch-2017/episodes/28

Answer (score -2):

Yes, filter can be good solution.

Just check in the filter, if author of that model is equal to authenticated user. If not, then reject it.